# Reading a protocol buffer file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, protocol-buffers

I am making requests to a public transportation API for data analysis. Several files are in JSON format, which is easy to deal with; however, some files are in `.protobuf` format.

I am curious how to parse these files into a human-readable format. For example, if I open the `.protobuf` file in a text editor, this is what I receive:

```
1"$
+(B���uC-(�̉�B
1462;
2"6

    741127020 *F
�ZB�����C-(�̉�B
1583<
3"7

    719255020 *10
K�B�8��C-FH@(�̉�B
1220<
4"7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protobuffer is a binary format, so it's not human readable in it's raw state. To read it, go get the [python bindings from Google](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/python-sample) and install with:

```
pip install --upgrade gtfs-realtime-bindings
```

Once you have those, you can download the pb file or read it locally very easily:

```
from google.transit import gtfs_realtime_pb2
import urllib.request 

feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()
pb_url = "http://someURL/someFile.pb"

with urllib.request.urlopen(pb_url) as response:
    feed.ParseFromString(response.read())
    print(feed)
```

This will give you something like:

```
header {
  gtfs_realtime_version: "1.0"
  incrementality: FULL_DATASET
  timestamp: 1579313685
}
entity {
  id: "10-abc-O-1"
  trip_update {
    trip {
      trip_id: "10-1622-O-1"
    }
...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. NOTE:: take a look at the hyperlink Mark provided - you must instantiate ```feed``` like so: ```from google.transit import gtfs_realtime_pb2
import urllib

feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()```